# Clean Architecture android

Tags: java, android, rxjava, mvp, dagger2

Начал в своем MVP юзать интерактор)
При этом Rx я не использовал) В Interactor`е я инжектил ретрофит и отправлял запрос)

Сейчас изучаю RxJava. Вроде бы принцип понял. Есть Observable и observer. Окей) Могу связать это с Retrofit.

Стоит задача: отправить запрос на сервер и полученные данные отобразить в RecyclerView.

Как я это вижу: я создаю model , view, presenter,interactor.
Инжекчу ретрофит в интерактор, упрощаю код ретрофита с помощью RxJava + лямбда и далее делаем все как обычно.

Но что-то мне кажется, что тут что-то не-то. 
То-ли использование Рх тут мало, то-ли нужно переходить на клин-архитектуру так как идет такая связка Даггер-МВП-Рх

Посоветуйте, как правильно решить такую простую задачу?

Comment: имплементацию сервиса инжектите в интерактор? тогда все ок. можно даже без rx обойтись. на чистую архитектуру переходить однозначно стоит.

Answer (score 0):

Пишете даггер модуль в котором `@Provides` метод для ретрофита

Ретрофит запросы возвращают `Observable<ResponseModel>` или `Single<ResponseModel>` если результат приходит один раз

Инжектите ретрофит в интерактор.

Интерактор получает данные ( `Observable<ResponseModel>`) из ретрофита, преобразует их в необходимый вид (через `.map()` допустим) для презентера и в `.subscribe()` прокидывает презентеру готовые данные.

Это всё. Всё вы правильно думаете, это и есть модная clean architecture

Если есть какие либо сомнения, при применении RxJava/Dagger смотрите в [гайд лайны по clean architecture от Google](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)

Answer (score 0):

Давайте разберемся в терминологии. [Модель в MVP - это](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-View-Presenter)

> Модель (англ. Model) — хранит в себе всю бизнес-логику, при необходимости получает данные из хранилища.

Интерактор это тоже бизнес логика, значит модель и интерактор - это одно и тоже в MVP.

У вас в предложенной логике все корректно. Если вы считаете, что RxJava мало, то начните его использовать во `View`, в связках `View-Presenter`, `Presenter-Model` (довольно подробно можно прочесть это в [Model-View-Intent](http://hannesdorfmann.com/android/model-view-intent) архитектуре). В вашем случае можно вообще убрать RxJava из стека, и [заменить это корутинами](https://medium.com/exploring-android/android-networking-with-coroutines-and-retrofit-a2f20dd40a83), для работы с ретрофитом это можно будет сделать достаточно просто.